# SHOW TOP 1 in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Here's the query

```
SELECT concat(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME) AS NAME, HIREDATE from EMPLOYEE ORDER BY HIREDATE
WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

I've been trying to use rownum function but I keep getting the error - "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended".

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT concat(FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME) AS NAME, HIREDATE from EMPLOYEE ORDER BY HIREDATE  )
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: Please check for duplicates and close the question before answering questions that are obvious duplicates.